# Is it possible to focus gravitational force to a point?

Tags: gravity, energy

I'm new to these kinds of discussions and I don't have broad knowledge in physics, and I don't know whether it's a proper question or not.

While in a discussion with my friend, a question has raised about gravitational force.
In real life, we can see that focusing energy to a single point to use it in a more efficient way. For example, we can focus sunlight to a point by using some lens, focusing wind power using a specific surface, etc.

Like these examples, can we focus the gravitational force to a point? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Light can be focused in part because it is a wave.  A *force* is not a wave.

We're pretty sure that gravitational waves exist, but they are so weak that they have never been *directly* observed, despite efforts to do so.

So it may be theoretically possible to focus a gravitational wave, but as a practical matter it is impossible.

Comment: Just adding a note that since this comment was posted, gravitational waves have been directly observed by LIGO.

Comment: There's probably a good argument that, even in the theoretical case, the Kardashev Type III+ civilization that could pull it off (by arranging matter on a galactic scale to focus waves from a neutron star or black hole merger, if that's even possible) could probably achieve the same goal (destroying something?) with a lot less effort; i.e. if I may compare cost/benefit of an engineering project to chemical reactions, the "focus gravitational waves to achieve something" project is more analogous to an endothermic reaction than an exothermic one with a large "difficulty" barrier.

Comment: It looks like you don't have to consider gravity as a force. General relativity defines it as the curvature of space-time.

Comment: We can make a lens for light because light interacts with matter.  Does gravity interact with anything?

Answer (score 1):

Gravity is understood as the curvature of spacetime. So focussing a curvature to a point would mean making the curvature a point. And that would be the end of geodesics. Such curvature is possible when the density becomes infinite but there are many arguments against singularity.
So I guess, the answer to the question is **we don't know**